# iOS: Navigation Style: Navigator, Browser, Editor

Tags: ios, uikit, interface-builder, uinavigationbar

On a `UINavigationBarItem` in Interface Builder, there is a dropdown for the style showing: `Navigator`, `Editor`, `Browser`. Anyone know what this selections means and what the options do?

[image: Interface Builder Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are new styles introduced in iOS 16.

They are illustrated in this video from WWDC 2022:

[image: Slide from WWDC2022 video showing Navigator, Browser, Editor styles]

See also [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/3987969-style).

Comment: A complete summary of this video including images and direct links is available if need be⟹ https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/wwdc/nota11y/2022/2210068/ 